# how do i pass json data in browser url as addressbar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, url, request, urlencode

I would like to pass Json data in URL as appending to parameter like below
 `localhost:3000/projects?name={"Name":"Hego","address":"Nano-4"}`

As its won't accept it.

My thoughts, we need to encode Json data first and passing encoded json data will work.

Why we need to encode Json in url? share your thoughts

Comment: Did you find answer for this? I am also facing the same problem. Any advice?

Comment: @Inaccessible, Yes. hope we couldn't pass direct json format in URL but we can pass encoded Json data. Like we can encode the json data from http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

Use params method of jquery to convert this json into query params

```
e.g. params = $.params({"Name":"Hego","address":"Nano-4"})
```

Comment: manually i want to enter in URL as when i hit enter it should response.

Comment: Entering json with URL in browser address itself.